# How do I detect the directory a php file is in

Tags: php

I have a PHP file that I need it to detect it's directory it's in. In my case I want it to return `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\`

I think that this is pretty straightforward but if there is something you don't understand just comment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In PHP 5.3: `__DIR__`

In lower version: `dirname(__FILE__)`

Answer (score 3):

The magic-constant **[`__FILE__`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)** contains the full path to the file in which you write it.

The **[`dirname`](http://fr.php.net/dirname)** function returns the path to the directory corresponding to a file.

So, in your case, to get the path to the directory containing your file, you can use :

```
echo dirname(__FILE__);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the directory the file is in, you may find the directory that corresponds to the web server's `/` URI (`http://www.example.com/` URL)  useful.  That's stored in `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`